# ag-grid + templateUrl crashes in IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, ag-grid

I just implemented ag-grid, but found that IE9 crashes when using cellTemplates with angular compiled templates inside.

Did any of you encounter this and maybe found a workaround?

How to reproduce:

Head here (http://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-cell-template/index.php)  with IE, and from DevTools, select IE9.

It will crash because of the angular compiled templates. Not sure what I can do about it.

(I also opened an issue on GitHub on this: https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/521 )

EDIT:

Debugged it, there's an infinite loop because an update to an array from one method, is not visible to another method somehow...

The infinite loop is:
getTemplate, (wait in line until the call ends), call ends, template added to cache, run callback, callback doesn't see the template in templateCache, creates another callback, adds it to the queue, and so on.
(code from ag-grid below).

```
// returns the template if it is loaded, or null if it is not loaded
        // but will call the callback when it is loaded
        TemplateService.prototype.getTemplate = function (url, callback) {
            var templateFromCache = this.templateCache[url];
            if (templateFromCache) {
                return templateFromCache;
            }
            var callbackList = this.waitingCallbacks[url];
            var that = this;
            if (!callbackList) {
                // first time this was called, so need a new list for callbacks
                callbackList = [];
                this.waitingCallbacks[url] = callbackList;
                // and also need to do the http request
                var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
                client.onload = function () {
                    that.handleHttpResult(this, url);
                };
                client.open("GET", url);
                client.send();
            }
            // add this callback
            if (callback) {
                callbackList.push(callback);
            }
            // caller needs to wait for template to load, so return null
            return null;
        };
        TemplateService.prototype.handleHttpResult = function (httpResult, url) {
            if (httpResult.status !== 200 || httpResult.response === null) {
                console.warn('Unable to get template error ' + httpResult.status + ' - ' + url);
                return;
            }
            // response success, so process it
            this.templateCache[url] = httpResult.response;
            // inform all listeners that this is now in the cache
            var callbacks = this.waitingCallbacks[url];
            for (var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
                var callback = callbacks[i];
                // we could pass the callback the response, however we know the client of this code
                // is the cell renderer, and it passes the 'cellRefresh' method in as the callback
                // which doesn't take any parameters.
                callback();
            }
            if (this.$scope) {
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    that.$scope.$apply();
                }, 0);
            }
        };
        return TemplateService;
    })();
```

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the issue.
In IE9, the template is on responseText inside the response.
In IE10+ and all other browsers it's on response.

So in order to fix it, in the above code, instead of:

```
     // response success, so process it
     this.templateCache[url] = httpResult.response;
```

I added:

```
     // response success, so process it
     //in IE9 the response is in - responseText
     this.templateCache[url] = httpResult.response || httpResult.responseText;
```

For future reference, adding the answer here.
Had nothing to do with Angular. :)

UPDATE:
https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/521

Code got into the repo :)
Thanks Niall Crosby (ceolter).